# Solve an inseparable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this equation?
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y}{x(xy^\frac32-1)}$$
I tried to separate the variables,yet it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

$$x(xy\sqrt{y}-1)dy=ydx$$
$$x^2y\sqrt{y}dy=ydx+xdy$$
$$(xy)^2\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y}}dy=d(xy)$$
$$2\int\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}dy=\int\dfrac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2}$$
$$2\sqrt{y}=\dfrac{-1}{xy}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try substituting $y{\left(x\right)}=x^{-\frac23}f{\left(x\right)}$. Differentiating this relation we have

$$y^{\prime}=\frac{f^{\prime}}{x^{\frac23}}-\frac{2\,f}{3x^{\frac53}}.$$

Then, the ODE becomes

$$\frac{f^{\prime}}{x^{\frac23}}-\frac{2\,f}{3x^{\frac53}}=\frac{f}{x^{\frac53}\left(f^{\frac32}-1\right)}$$

$$\implies\,f^{\prime}=\frac{2\,f}{3x}+\frac{f}{x\left(f^{\frac32}-1\right)}$$

$$\implies\,f^{\prime}=\frac{f}{x}\left[\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{\left(f^{\frac32}-1\right)}\right],$$

which is indeed separable.

Comment: "which is indeed separable" Is it?

Comment: @Did It indeed is. Isn't it??? If you see an error that I missed, please share

Comment: Indeed it is. My bad, sorry for the noise. :-)

Comment: I found another solution, we can write this equation in a different way

Comment: dx/dy = (x(x(y)^3/2-1))/y=(x^2)(y^1/2)-(x/y)                                                         
         dx/dy + (x/y) =   (x^2)(y^1/2)     (Bernoulli's equation)